# Exporting Volume Group From One Server To Another Difficulties

Tags: linux, ubuntu, lvm

I'm attempting to migrate a volume group from one Ubuntu 12.10 server to a new Ubuntu 12.10 Server(upgrades). My existing VG is spread across 3 physical drives, and within the VG is 2 logical volumes. I would like to move the three drives and the entire VG to the new machine and I'm following these steps: (naturally sudo is implied, and I'm doing this over ssh)
1. I unmount both LVs
 - no problems encountered with this step
2. I set the VG to inactive using "vgchange -an fileserver"
 - I get the response: 0 logical volume(s) in volume group "fileserver" now active
3. I enter: vgexport fileserver
 - and I get the response: Volume group "fileserver" has active logical volumes

if I run lvscan it displays all my LVs as ACTIVE which is clearly not what I want. As far as I know, I use the vgchange command to set all LVs in my VG to INACTIVE and even though the cli is telling me that 0 logical volumes in my VG are active after doing this, running lvscan on the very next line is telling me they are indeed active and thus I'm not able to export.

can anybody out there shed some light?

Answer (score 1):

After a few days of searching for a solution I found this:

http://slashzeroconf.wordpress.com/2008/07/11/lvm2-remove-or-deactivate-problem/

which helped me out a lot. Using "dmsetup remove " did set the drive as inactive and I was able to export to my new system.